Create Visualization From Elasticsearch Aggregation Query In Kibana
I'm using elasticsearch query to calculate increase of failed query operations (ignoring any decreases)
POST /index_pattern/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        { "match": { "labels.response_status": "success" } }
      ],
       "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "labels.operation_type": "query"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "requests_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "15s"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "requests": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "http_requests_total"
          }
        },
        "increase_over_time": {
          "serial_diff": {
            "buckets_path": "requests"
          }
        },
        "adjusted_increase_over_time": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "diff": "increase_over_time",
              "current_requests": "requests"
            },
            "script": "params.diff < 0 ? 0 : params.diff"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "total_increase": {
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "requests_over_time>adjusted_increase_over_time"
      }
    }
  }
}

The result of this query look like this,
{
          "key_as_string" : "2024-09-03T04:58:00.000Z",
          "key" : 1725339480000,
          "doc_count" : 7,
          "requests" : {
            "value" : 8.0
          },
          "increase_over_time" : {
            "value" : 0.0
          },
          "adjusted_increase_over_time" : {
            "value" : 0.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2024-09-03T04:58:15.000Z",
          "key" : 1725339495000,
          "doc_count" : 8,
          "requests" : {
            "value" : 10.0
          },
          "increase_over_time" : {
            "value" : 2.0
          },
          "adjusted_increase_over_time" : {
            "value" : 2.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "2024-09-03T04:58:30.000Z",
          "key" : 1725339510000,
          "doc_count" : 8,
          "requests" : {
            "value" : 10.0
          },
          "increase_over_time" : {
            "value" : 0.0
          },
          "adjusted_increase_over_time" : {
            "value" : 0.0
          }
        },
    "total_increase" : {
      "value" : 2.0
    }

I want to create a metric type visualization that shows the value of total_increase and a line chart or histogram that shows the trend of total_increase over time. Is it possible to create a visualization based on the result of this query?
I'm using Kibana version 7.17.18
